# GLUT Screen Resize

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am trying to write a function that makes the screen full size and normal size and more Importantly while I resize the screen size to normal size it puts back on the position it was before I full sized it.. how can I do it...

Here Is what I have done

```
//global Variables
int scr_pos_x = 100, scr_pos_y = 150;

//somewhere else in main method
glutInitWindowPosition(scr_pos_x, scr_pos_y);
....
glutKeyboardFunc(myKeyboard);

//myKeyBoardFunction
void myKeyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y){
    if(key == 'f'){
        int scr_pos_x = glutGet((GLenum)GLUT_WINDOW_X);
        int scr_pos_y = glutGet((GLenum)GLUT_WINDOW_Y);
        cout << " while f press "<<scr_pos_x <<" "<<scr_pos_y << endl; // to check
        glutFullScreen();
    }else if(key=='x'){
        cout << " while x press "<<scr_pos_x <<" "<<scr_pos_y << endl; // to check
        glutPositionWindow(scr_pos_x, scr_pos_y);
        glutReshapeWindow(640, 480); 
    }
}
```

When I press 'f' I can see that the scr_pos_x and scr_pos_y are set up to the appropriate value but when I press 'x' those values somehow changes to 100 and 150. What am I missing??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(key == 'f'){
    int scr_pos_x = glutGet((GLenum)GLUT_WINDOW_X);
    int scr_pos_y = glutGet((GLenum)GLUT_WINDOW_Y);
    cout << " while f press "<<scr_pos_x <<" "<<scr_pos_y << endl; // to check
    glutFullScreen();
}
```

Here you create two *entirely new* variables called `scr_pos_x` and `scr_pos_y` that last until the end of that `if` block.  They override the global ones.

Drop the `int` at the beginning of the two declarations so that the `glutGet()`s overwrite the *global* `scr_pos_x` and `scr_pos_y` variables.

Comment: Thank you that worked fine. I dont know what I was doing.. I got it. Thanks again